# Get MethodInfo for Include method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using the following to get the OrderBy method:

```
MethodInfo orderBy = typeof(Queryable)
  .GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" && x.GetParameters()
  .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
  .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));
```

But how to do the same for Include method? I couldn't find it in Queryable ...

Comment: Include is not in the IQueryable class but in the EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions from Entity Framework "typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)"

Comment: I only get 5 methods from QueryableExtensions and none of them is Include.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment for EF Core.

Comment: Yes, it is in EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions. Thanks

Comment: @JonathanMagnan If you want add you answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include is not in the Queryable class but in the **EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions** class from Entity Framework

```
var type = typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions);
```

Comment: `IQueryable` isn't a class, it's an interface.

Comment: @Servy fixed the interface mistake!

Comment: None of the LINQ methods are in `IQueryable`.  They're in the *class* `Queryable`.  That was your mistake.